# Sort by count of Join table with field value like X

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table and reporting_events table. reporting_event belongs to user. I used join on users table like.

```
   users.joins(:reporting_events).where(reporting_events: { name: sort_column } )
```

Here I get users with reporting event names as sort_column.

I want to list users if reporting_events name is sort_column or if user does't have a reporting_event with name sort_column.

I want to user order after this where clause like:

```
  users.joins(:reporting_events).where(reporting_events: { name: sort_column } ).group("users.id").order("count(reporting_events) #{sort_direction} nulls last")
```

The problem is that this returns only those users with reporting events with the sort_column name. I want to return all the users always, and to order them by count of reporting events with the name if the reporting_event exists.

Comment: "I want to list users if reporting_events name is sort_column or if user does't have a reporting_event with name sort_column." - doesn't it mean just "all users"? :)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Actually yes. But I want to sort by the count of reporting events with the specific name. And if no such reporting events exists for users, those users should be at last of the list.

Comment: I ended up using a sql like   join = <<~SQL
      LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_events
        ON reporting_events.user_id = users.id
        AND reporting_events.name = '#{sort_column}'
      SQL
@KonstantinStrukov

Comment: Could you explain how this question apply to rails 3 and 4, two really different rails versions? please stop with that

Comment: @AlterLagos In that case, the question is not also specific to ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by creating custom sql query.

```
 join = <<~SQL
      LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_events
        ON reporting_events.user_id = users.id
        AND reporting_events.name = '#{sort_column}'
      SQL

user.joins(join)
```

Reference: https://exlabs.com/insights/left-join-for-advanced-rubyists